# TreeNode Selection Problems in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Whenever I click outside the tree nodes text, on the control part, it tigers a node click event- but doesn't highlight the node. I am unsure why this is happening.

I want the node to be selected on a click- when you click the nodes text- not the whitespace- I only assume that the nodes width reaches across the whole Treenode?  I have the Treeview on dock.fill mode if that has something to do with it- I tried everything but can't get it to behave correctly.

Maybe someone will know what's going on.

Update: 
            `if (e.Location.IsEmpty)
            {`

Seems to work better- but still selects the node in the blank place where there is no text- Obviously the node width extends across the whole treeview it seems?

Is there a better way to accomplish what I want? Or is that the best way?

UPDATE: Previous idea isn't working- sigh- I thought it did it but it didn't.

New Problem : I think part of the problem is related to the focus now when I switch from treeview.

UPDATE-

The only code I came up with about disabling right mouse click to select node on beforeSelect event is

```
 if (MouseButtons == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;

            }
```

But it didn't work- any help is appreciated- following suggestions of only answer, for more details.

Comment: As far as I remember you can just check Selected and return from the event handler if it is null

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# - Problem with NodeMouseClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190751/c-problem-with-nodemouseclick) - I think the answer to this will solve your problem.

Comment: The NodeMouseClick event fires *very* early, giving code a chance to do something meaningful with it.  One of them that's built in is "only meaningful when the text is clicked".  You almost always want the AfterSelect event, last one that fires.

Comment: Take a look to answer by Cody Gray to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333093/treeview-node-is-highlighted-even-i-did-not-right-click-on-the-node/4333264#4333264

Comment: Yes, I checked out the post Javed- From the post it seems there is a glitch in the way the wrapper handles the selection event in TreeView. I am going to test out the AfterSelect- but I have a feeling that it might be futile. Hopefully, the post is wrong and you can solve it without inheritance and overriding right click.  If that is the only way- I will live with the ghosting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the treeView.HitTest method to determine which part of the node has been clicked.

```
private bool IsClickOnText(TreeView treeView, TreeNode node, Point location)
{
    var hitTest = treeView1.HitTest(location);

    return hitTest.Node == node
        && hitTest.Location == TreeViewHitTestLocations.Label;
}

private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    if(IsClickOnText(treeView1, e.Node, e.Location))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("click");
    }
}

private void treeView1_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == TreeViewAction.ByMouse)
    {
        var position = treeView1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);        
        e.Cancel = !IsClickOnText(treeView1, e.Node, position);
    }
}
```

Comment: My FullRowSelect property is false though, that is what I thought in the very beginning.

Comment: Do you use WinForms or something else?

Comment: I use WinForms TreeView and it shows the property as false on FullRowSelect.

Comment: That seems a much longer way of doing `bool clickedItem = e.Node.Bounds.Contains(e.Location);` in the `NodeMouseClick` event.

Comment: Thanks, that made it much better- however, I have a ContextMenuStrip assigned to the TreeControl and whenever I right click to access it (over no node labels)- it selects a node like before for a second then goes back to the first node.

Comment: Add mouse butteon check into NodeMouseClick

Comment: Thanks Viacheslav for all the help- I am confused about all this mouse node clicking for now, will have to ponder it later. I don't understand why a right click still selects it when you helped check the mouse clicks for selecting on labels. and I am unsure how to add mouse button checks- I am not a good programmer lol- so I will have to think on it when my mind is less flustered.

Comment: I been trying to make it where the mouse right button that brings up the contextmenustrip doesn't select the node while not over the label (on the treeview canvas) and without luck- If anyone wants to help me figure out how, respond away :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the .AfterSelect and/or .BeforeSelect events to handle the selection processing instead of the .Click event. Then it will select the node only when you click on the text, and it won't fire .AfterSelect or .BeforeSelect when you click on the white space.

Comment: I will try that- I only checked for BeforeSelect - How do you cancel the selection event or check for it through AfterSelect? The EventArgs doesn't have a cancel property?